# How to change the schema by arg text in postgres procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION newfunction (Schema1 text, Schema2 text)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$ 
.
.
.
insert into [Schema1].table (name,phone,address,......)
select name,phone,address,..... from [Schema2].table where....;
```

I want to change the schema by arg text
is this possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL throughout:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      E'INSERT INTO %I.tab (...)\n'
      'SELECT ... FROM %I.tab WHERE ...',
      schema1,
      schema2
   );
```